# I’ve been researching upon Acrostic YHWH examples in the Hebrew Bible. Could they be useful in analyzing textual anomalies regarding, spelling?

Tags: genesis, exodus, tetragrammaton, reference-request

I'm looking for a reference regarding the Acrostics of the Tetragrammaton to be found in the Hebrew Bible.

Most seem only to know of those where the beginning letters of four consecutive words spell “The Hallowed Name” forward, but they also occur in three other ways. Beginning letters spelling in reverse (HWHY), also with the ending letters of four consecutive words (forward and reverse).

The text of Esther has one of each in about 3,200 words. In the “burning bush” narrative there is also such a set (Ex. 3:2-4:17), the first is right in the middle of Moses' question! Actually together Genesis and Exodus have 20, 5 of each type in what appears to be a pattern. Has anyone written about this? I was aware of E.W Bullinger’s Companion Bible, App. 60. The suggestion to check out franknette.net/article.php?article I’d=126 was appreciated. He unfortunately didn’t search out the End Letters Acrostics from what I read. Also seems to have missed the Begin Forward noted in another question on this site (Gen.1:31-2:1). My research has been old school, scanning by eye the text of my BHS Bible. Personally I can think of no grammatical or literary reasons why the four types of Acrostics spelling The Hallowed Name should be found in equal distribution. If they are in the text by design, they may explain some anomaly’s, such as, Why is ה prefixed to “the sixth day”?

Comment: See [Bible code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_code).

Comment: Don't know if this article will help as the author's findings for Gen. & Exo. differ from yours.  https://www.franknelte.net/article.php?article_id=126. Also saw an article that said 3 manuscripts actually have the YHVH acrostics of Esther in red. Thought that was interesting!